# VBA Property Chaining?

Tags: vba

If you can use method chaining to get to a results such as  the line below

```
cReportcard.student("doe").Metric("math").score
```

How do you take a property back down the chain?

I have a collection of custom classes for subjects (e.g., math, language arts, pe...). The custom class has a student,score, teacher, classroom, period.

How can I

```
cReportcard.student("doe").Metric("math").score=0.96
```

and have the value chain backward to the originating class collection?

I imagine this to be something like the "parent" property of the Worksheet class. I just cannot figure out how to do it.

So far I have designed the a table scheme with 4 tables (Student, Metric, Grades, Periods)

```
Student(ID [pk], NAME, DOB)
Metric (ID [pk], NAME)
Period (ID [pk], METRIC_ID [fk], GRADE_LEVEL, START_TIME, LENGTH, CLASS_RM, TEACHER_ID [fk])
Grade (ID [pk], PERIOD_END_DATE, PERIOD_ID [fk], STUDENT_ID [fk], METRIC_SCORE
```

)

Comment: What do you mean by "chain backwards to the original collection"?

Comment: The above method chaining example pulls one of the metric classes out of the collection and passes it forward as 'Me' then you can harvest the score from that new class. How do you change the Score and have it reflect back to the original collection?

Comment: What are the relationships among the classes? It looks like: reportcard has a collection of students and each student has a collection of metrics and each metric has several properties, of which score is one. Is that correct?

Comment: Actually, can you just add the source for those classes? That would really help clear up some of the confusion about how they are related.

Comment: @blackhawk you are correct. The idea is not much different than Forms("someform").controls("txtSomeControl").value = "This is cool".  I don't have any real code yet, I am working on a UML and mentally I cannot get my brain wrapped around this concept.

Comment: So what is the problem with your code that you need to figure out? The code you posted will work fine if you 1. declare an instance of Reportcard, 2. create a new Student and add it to the student collection of Reportcard with the right name, 3. create the new Metric and add it to the metric collection of the student, then use your code just like you did: `cReportcard.student("doe").Metric("math").score`

Comment: I think that if you have things defined correctly then something like `cReportcard.student("doe").Metric("math").score=0.96` should just work -- meaning set the score property of the metric object corresponding to key "math" of the student objects corresponding to key "doe" equal to 0.96. Student object would need to have collections of metrics and reportcard objects would have to have collections of students -- but it should be straightforward. Are you saying that you can't get that line to work?

Comment: @JohnColeman I have not tried any real code yet. I guess I was not ready to ask the question here but I think blackhawk is on to something. In my UML I don't think I have my Metric class and Metrics collection drawn right.

Comment: @Blackhawk I don't know if it will work or not. Right now I am just doing the UML. I have asked here in the past about method chaining and finally got it to work and understand it. But that has been only to retrieve data (properties) not set properties.

Comment: @FredWilson it all depends upon your use cases. If all you want to do is keep track of those relationships in a single dimension (reportcard has multiple students, a student has multiple metrics, a metric has multiple properties like Score), the way I described it would be fine. If you want to do something different later, like find out which students have the "math" metric or add up all the scores for students whose name starts with "M", you might want to design it differently.

Comment: OH! I see - don't implement it with method chaining (I assume you mean [this kind of method chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining)) - use nested collections of classes.

Comment: @Blackhawk I have the transactional data tables normalized to 3NF. I also have a star data warehouse to 3NF. Now I am trying to understand how to match a custom class to them.

Comment: That changes everything - you should probably add that to your question. I'm going to assume you have table Student and table Metric where they only have basic info, then you have table Reportcard which references the other two tables. I'm also assuming that the assuming that one row of Reportcard references one student and one metric. In that case, you need to decide how the classes will be used. Will you just be changing grades the way you showed? Will you also want to look up students starting with the metric?

Answer (score 2):

I think you might want to put a little more time into defining your exact use cases to make sure those tables will quickly allow you to perform any operations you will need. But assuming that's the final structure, I would design the classes like this:

clsGrade:

```
'It would be better to have them all private and provide get/set properties
Private ID As Long
Public Student As clsStudent
Public Period As clsPeriod
Public Period_End_Date As Date
Public Metric_Score As Long

'This assumes that, per your example, the only fields necessary to find a "grade" are student name and metric
Public Sub Load(studentName As String, Metric As String)
    Dim rs As Recordset
    'SQL query to get the grade for a particular student/metric

    Set Student = New clsStudent
    Student.Load rs!STUDENT_ID

    Set Period = New clsPeriod
    Period.Load rs!PERIOD_ID

End Sub

Public Sub Save()
    'SQL query to save the grade

    'You would have to decide whether or not this cascades and saves the Student/Period/Metric info as well.
    Student.Save
    Period.Save
End Sub
```

clsMetric:

```
'It would be better to have them all private and provide get/set properties
Private ID As Long
Public Name As String

Public Sub Load(ID As Long)
    'SQL to load a metric by ID
End Sub

Public Sub Save()
    'SQL to save the metric
End Sub
```

clsPeriod:

```
'It would be better to have them all private and provide get/set properties
Private ID As Long
Public Metric As clsMetric
Public Grade_Level As Long
Public Start_Time As Date
Public Length As Date
Public Class_Rm As String
Public Teacher_ID As Long

Public Sub Load(ID As Long)
    Dim rs As Recordset
    'SQL to load a period by ID

    'Also load the child metric
    Set Metric = New clsMetric
    Metric.Load rs!METRIC_ID

End Sub

Public Sub Save()
    'SQL to save the period

    'Also save the child metric
    Metric.Save
End Sub
```

clsStudent:

```
'It would be better to have them all private and provide get/set properties
Private ID As Long
Public Name As String
Public DOB As Date

Public Sub Load(ID As Long)
    'SQL to load a student by ID
End Sub

Public Sub Save()
    'SQL to save the student
End Sub
```

And then you could use them like so:

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dim grade As clsGrade
    Set grade = New clsGrade
    grade.Load "doe", "math"
    grade.Metric_Score = 0.96
    grade.Save
End Sub
```

If you want to streamline it and get fancy, you can do the Get/Let Properties and add a "dirty" bit to each class to keep track of whether anything has been changed since it was loaded or not. That way you don't save information which hasn't changed.

Comment: your example lends itself to a follow on question, it appears that your example would open and close recordsets a lot. Is this better than loading up a class collection one time and use the class collection? The first go around with my exercise is to take a bazzilon spreadsheets and import them into Access. I was going to do this via this custom class to massage and validate the data. The follow on would be to use the custom class collections as a report builder along with a small data mart for some BI and GIS stuff.

Comment: @FredWilson Have you used Access before? Tools are provided for importing data simply from a wide variety of data sources including Excel spreadsheets. Massage and validate your data using queries - you can run the queries from code if you wish. I would strongly suggest using the built-in reporting capability before constructing your own from scratch. VBA does not provide any shortcut ORM capability, so I find that unless the situation requires a lot of logic or calculation, queries are the way to go. You can even use VBA functions within queries if need be.

Comment: I use MS Access all the time. I just have never jumped off into custom class collections. I understand the built in import features but the data I am importing is not structured in a way to that lends itself to importing that way. Likewise, the reporting that is desired is in MS Excel. Finally, the GIS data needs to be processed data so I figured that a small data mart was in order. All of it via Access makes it simple and cheap with what is on the desktop now.